# Gradle "flattens" directory in war

Tags: gradle, war

build.gradle:

...

```
configurations {
    dartLibrary
}

dependencies {
   // Dart - web has a lot of subdirs... (packages and so forth)
   dartLibrary fileTree(dir: 'src/main/dart/web')
}

war {
   into('/') {
      from configurations.dartLibrary
   }
}
```

This copies all the files form src/main/dart/web into my war but the problem is that it "flattens" the structure. Means all files from web and its subdirs are merged into the / of my war.

Pls. help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration`s are flat `FileCollection`s. You need to remove the indirection (and can also leave out the call to `fileTree`):

```
war {
    from "src/main/dart/web"
}
```